# Rails 3 - Compare part of integer with other integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, integer

I'm working for almost 4 weeks with Ruby on Rails now, so consider me as a beginner.

When performing a conditional find query, I need to compare a part of an integer (put in a string..) with another integer.

`@invs = Inv.find(:all, :conditions => {:cnr => INTEGER_TO_BE_COMPARED_TO })`

Well, I found a way to get a certain part of an integer and wrote the following method:

```
def get_part_of_int
    @r = Integer((@cnr % 10000000)/100000.0)
    @r = "%02d" % @r
    @r.to_s
end
```

This should give the output `@r = 01` from `@cnr = 40138355`

The target is to only show `invs` with e.g. `01` as second and third digit.

I'm using:
Rails 3.2.8
Ruby 1.9.3p194

Thank you all in advance.

== Edit: ==
I realised there is no question mark in my post.. And there is some confusion.

The value of the column name `cnr` should be stripped to the 2nd and 3rd digit and be compared to a string e.g. `01`.
Thank you @Salil for you suggestion.
However this doesn't work.. But I understand the way of using it. The following will convert the string `:cnr` to `:nr`.
`Inv.find(:all, :conditions => {:cnr.to_s[1,2] => '01' })`
Is there a way to compare a part of the value of the column with e.g. `01`?

Maybe I should think the other way around. Is it possible to search for `cnrs` with the 2nd and 3rd digit e.g. `01`? The trick is that these numbers are always as 2nd and 3rd digit. I assume a fuzzy search with e.g. Solr doesn't work, because when searching for `01` I don't want the `cnr` `40594013`.

Can this be done in some way?

Thank you in advance and my apologies for confusing you.

Comment: I'm quite confused... So the question is how to get the second and third digit from a integer?

Comment: what is the datataype of cnr filed?

Comment: @halfelf, no, I figured that out with the posted method. But the method Salil posted beneath, seems much (much!) cleaner.
In this case, a db-column is named `cnr` and has the a value e.g. `40138355` or `40538492`. Both numbers should be compared to e.g. `01` as 2nd and 3rd digit. When this is `true`, the record should be displayed.

@AmitPatel, the datatype is a String. But can be converted with `.to_i`

Answer (score 1):

if your question `is how to get the second and third digit from a integer?`
You can use following

```
40138355.to_s[1,2] ##This will give you "01"
```

EDITED  Ref:- [Substring](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_function_substring.php)

```
@invs = Inv.find(:all, :conditions => ["SUBSTRING(cnr,1,2) =?", @cnr.to_s[1,2] ])
```

Comment: just FYI `"01".to_i gives you 1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer to that question. However, this was not the exact question. You made me realise that there is not even one question mark in my post. So I understand the confusedness.
The value of the column name `cnr` should be stripped to the 2nd and 3rd digit. Your method therefore is great and much cleaner than the one I posted/wrote.
However, this I cannot put in a `.find` query.
`Inv.find(:all, :conditions => {:cnr.to_s[1,2] => '01' })`

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where did the `01` go? I guess this should be `@cnr.to_s[1,2]`?

Comment: I implemented your line and I didn't get any results. This is what happened:
`SELECT `inv`.* FROM `inv` WHERE (SUBSTRING(cnr,1,2) ='01')`
Can't figure out what I'm missing. But thanks again for your input.